# What happens if WinRT app terminated during file copy?

Tags: c++, winrt-async, storagefile

I am working on an application which will be performing async file copies through WinRT. I am wondering what will happen if my application calls CopyAsync on a Windows::Storage::StorageFile and then shortly thereafter is terminated by the OS (or suspended when the user switches away). My initial prototyping would lead me to believe that the file copy will be finished regardless of my app's state (it seemed to work for me). Does anyone know specifics on this?  Will Windows manage to complete the file copy or is it my task to realize this and restart the copy?

Answer (score 0):

Your file copy is not guaranteed to finish if the user moves away from the app, read this for more info: 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx#app_suspend

You need to use background tasks for that: 

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27411